# Create type for component based on props passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a component that looks like this:

```
<Button component='a' href='/'>
  Link
</Button>
```

I want to get the type definition of the `component` prop, so I can automatically include it in the props for the `Button` component. Any ideas on what the interface/type for the `Button` component should look like

Answer (score 1):

I've used this pattern before. Declare the `component` prop of type `React.ComponentType<T> | string`. Your `Button` component should look a bit like this:

```
export interface ButtonProps {
  component?: React.ComponentType<any>; // or React.ReactElement<any>["type"]
  href?: string;
  children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  const {
    component: Component = "button", // note: uppercase
    children,
    ...other
  } = props;

  return (
    <Component {...other}>
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. But how do I check that the `...other` props exist on the type for the button component?

Comment: @OluwakoredeFashokun `any` would cover it, but that's a bit of a hack. Perhaps use `React.ComponentType<React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> | React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>>`, or declare what props on the component you want to support.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Button` component could be typed like that:

```
import * as React from 'react';

type ButtonProps = {
    component: string,
    href: string,
}
type ButtonState = {}
export default class Button extends React.Component<ButtonProps , ButtonState > {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }
    render() { return <div/> }
}
```

I wrote a whole article on building a [TypeScript + React](https://github.com/ninofiliu/react-redux-webpack-typescript) app from A to Z, check it out for complete details and explanations!